# Get facebook friends in new facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get facebook friend list in php

```
$fql = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()+ORDER+BY+rand()+LIMIT+170&'.$access_token.'';
$fqlresult = file_get_contents($fql); 
 $f = json_decode($fqlresult, true);
```

but fql is not working anymore

Is there anyway to get friend list in new api.

Answer (score 0):

FQL is deprecated, but getting the friends is much easier with the Graph API anyway:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends

There are code examples how to do this for all important SDKs. Just keep in mind that it is not possible to get ALL friends anymore, you only get the friends who are using the App too.

There is also `invitable_friends` and `taggable_friends` though, take a look at the Facebook docs to find out what they are about:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/invitable_friends
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends

Comment: with default permissions can we get friend list of user. if yes please give me example sir.

Comment: you just need "user_friends" in the login process, does not even need to get approved by facebook

Comment: just add it in the scope parameter in FB.login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1

Comment: by using me/friends only getting users who used same app. Not getting whole friend list

Comment: yes, i mentionted that in my answer ;) - you don´t just get the whole friend list anymore, for privacy reasons.